# dont see the unknown column at all

Tags: mysql

My table description is as follows.

```
  CREATE TABLE `instruments` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `symbol` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `exchange` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `FullName` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `IPOYear` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Sector` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Industry` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

    COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

when I run a query against it, I get a error. How do I fix it as I don't see that column at all.

```
I get a error. 
SELECT  * FROM  INSTRUMENTS;
/* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column ' ' in 'field list' */
```

Comment: what does running "desc tablename" show?

Comment: My guess: You have copied the query from a MS-Word document that contains a controll byte which is shown as a space. Write the same query by hand - Do you get the same error?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like I had symbol invisible characters in my select statement due to cut/paste

Comment: And you should be consistent with uppercase/lowercase... If your table is called `instruments`, don't use it also as `INSTRUMENTS`. This will aso produce errors. *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a35fadfb27731a124e0a89d777d7b23c)*